# Как изменить input в Python?

Tags: python, строки, input

Пользователь вводит какой-то текст в терминале, например, слово "hello", но каждый введенный символ заменяется на желаемый мной, например "joke", причем после написания "joke" введенные пользователем символы просто стираются.

Пошаговый пример:

```
1a. h
1b. j
2a. je
2b. jo
3a. jol
3b. jok
4a. jokl
4b. joke
5a. jokeo
5b. joke
```

Как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: Объясните пошагово, что где и как будет происходить и изменяться на этом вашем примере, и приведите ваше собственное решение, которое не работает или хотя бы придуманный вами алгоритм

Comment: @EzikBro Открывается терминал, и там стоит input. И там текст, допустим "напишите hello". Человек пишет первую букву h, но вместо нее пишется j. Он написал hell (по буквам), но написалось joke. Пишет букву o (hello), но ничего не изменяется.

Comment: Добавьте это в ваш вопрос, отредактировав его

Comment: @EzikBro Добавил.

Comment: это не инпут менять, а перехватывать и изменять нажатие клавы

Comment: `pip3 install keyboard`

Comment: не ясно как именно происходит взаимодействие с программой, это раз. второе, может сами что-то попробуете или сбросите хоть какой-то вариант ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не нашел способа сделать это только встроенными модулями, но вы можете подключить модуль `keyboard` с помощью команды:

```
pip install keyboard
```

Данный модуль позволяет перехватывать ввод с клавиатуры, поэтому введенные символы не будут отображаться по умолчанию. Для того чтобы вводить собственные символы при вводе с клавиатуры, можно использовать `print(char, end = '')` или `stdout.write(char)`.

Пример кода:

```
from sys import stdout
import time
import keyboard

joke = 'joke'
n = -1
print('Input a hello:')
while True:
    t = keyboard.read_key()
    n += 1
    if n < len(joke):
        stdout.write(joke[n])
        stdout.flush()
    #задержка для того, чтобы долгое нажатие читалось как одно нажатие
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Также стоит отметить модуль `pynput`. Он также предоставляет возможность обрабатывать ввод каждой клавиши, но в более удобном виде. Примеры использования есть в документации к модулю.

Comment: Хороший ответ. Правда, как сделать так чтобы был ENTER в строке joke?